# Laravel Echo private channel is not listening in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, chat, laravel-echo

To create a real-time chat system for my flutter app, I am using Laravel Echo and Pusher Client. Unfortunately, even though I have included every configuration into my application, I am still not receiving a response from the pusher.

**Laravel Echo Configuration in Flutter**

```
    class LaravelEcho {
  static LaravelEcho? _singleton;
  static late Echo _echo;
  final String token;

  LaravelEcho._({
    required this.token,
  }) {
    _echo = createLaravelEcho(token);
  }

  factory LaravelEcho.init({
    required String token,
  }) {
    if (_singleton == null || token != _singleton?.token) {
      _singleton = LaravelEcho._(token: token);
    }

    return _singleton!;
  }

  static Echo get instance => _echo;

  static String get socketId => _echo.socketId() ?? "11111.11111111";
}


class PusherConfig {
  static const appId = "13***69";
  static const key = "e0131******a186b1d";
  static const secret = "46de951******14b205";
  static const cluster = "mt1";
  static const hostEndPoint = RemoteUrls.baseUrl;
  static const hostAuthEndPoint = "${hostEndPoint}broadcasting/auth";
  static const port = 6001;
}

PusherClient createPusherClient(String token) {
  PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
    wsPort: PusherConfig.port,
    encrypted: true,
    host: PusherConfig.hostEndPoint,
    cluster: PusherConfig.cluster,
    auth: PusherAuth(
      PusherConfig.hostAuthEndPoint,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer $token",
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
    ),
  );

  PusherClient pusherClient = PusherClient(
    PusherConfig.key,
    options,
    autoConnect: false,
    enableLogging: true,
  );

  return pusherClient;
}

Echo createLaravelEcho(String token) {
  return Echo(
    client: createPusherClient(token),
    broadcaster: EchoBroadcasterType.Pusher,
  );
}
```

**Trying to listen like way**

```
try {
  LaravelEcho.instance
      .channel('chat.${widget.recentChat.participants.first.inboxId}')
      .listen('.chat-message', (e) {
    print("laravel echo success: $e");
    if (e is PusherEvent) {
      if (e.data != null) {
        vLog(jsonDecode(e.data!));
        _handleNewMessage(jsonDecode(e.data!));
      }
    }
  }).error((err) {
    eLog(err);
    print("laravel echo error: $err");
  });
} catch (e) {
  print("err: $e");
}
```

**Console log error**

```
 com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://baseUrl.com/broadcasting/auth

at com.pusher.client.util.HttpAuthorizer.authorize(HttpAuthorizer.java:146)
W/System.err(21922):    at com.pusher.client.channel.impl.PrivateChannelImpl.getAuthResponse(PrivateChannelImpl.java:130)
W/System.err(21922):    at com.pusher.client.channel.impl.PrivateChannelImpl.toSubscribeMessage(PrivateChannelImpl.java:90)
W/System.err(21922):    at com.pusher.client.channel.impl.ChannelManager$1.run(ChannelManager.java:149)
W/System.err(21922):    at com.pusher.client.util.Factory$1.run(Factory.java:119)
W/System.err(21922):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err(21922):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err(21922):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://lsaeducation.com/broadcasting/auth
W/System.err(21922):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
W/System.err(21922):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
W/System.err(21922):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
W/System.err(21922):    at com.pusher.client.util.HttpAuthorizer.authorize(HttpAuthorizer.java:128)
W/System.err(21922):    ... 7 more
D/PusherClientPlugin(21922): [ON_ERROR]: message: Connection not authorized within timeout, code: 4009
D/PusherClientPlugin(21922): [DISCONNECTING]
D/PusherClientPlugin(21922): [DISCONNECTED]
```

How might this problem be resolved? Any advice or suggestions on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you